# How can i package my python application made using PyQt into installable file?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyqt5, installation

There are a lot of ways to create an executable file from python application, But can't find any way to package executable file to installable file in the ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) which is multiplatform and support for QT ootb, assuming that you want a single executable file:

```sh
pyinstaller --clean --windowed --onefile /path/to/main/python/file
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please tell me how to create an installer or built distribution from this..?